# Client side SSL with Spring-WS

Tags: ssl, spring-ws

I'm trying to use mutual authentication (certs on both client and server) but I'm then getting this error:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Then I found this class which I tried to use as a messageSender:
HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender

But I can't figure out how to setup keystores and truststores which I have configure with javax.net.ssl properties.
If possible I would like to do this setup in spring xml files so it can dynamically configured.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout here.

You just have to generate a certificate and place in JRE library path and no need to use any message sender.

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/

Certificate generator https://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java

Then if you face this exception `java.security.cert.CertificateException`

Then just override the verifier
`static {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                // HOST_ADDRESS = Endpoint host address
                if (hostname.equals(HOST_ADDRESS)) 
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
        });
    }`

Comment: How is it different from keytool -import -trustedcacerts ?